# Error when customizing Controls 2 SpinBox

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols2

When customizing a QtQuickControls2 SpinBox, I get this error in the console when closing my application :

> "There are still \"2\" items in the process of being created at engine destruction."

The number varies depending on how many Spinboxes are in the windows, it goes up for every indicator that was customized (two times per customized SpinBox : one for the up indicator, one for the down indicator). I tried commenting out each part of my custom code, as well as using the example code provided [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-spinbox), so I am positive that this is where the error comes from.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error ?

Main window code :

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow{
    width: 1600
    height: 900
    visible: true
    SpinBox_custom{

    }
}
```

Custom SpinBox_custom code :

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

SpinBox {
    id: control
    value: 50
    editable: true

    contentItem: TextInput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin : up.indicator.width
        anchors.leftMargin : down.indicator.width
        z: 2
        text: control.textFromValue(control.value, control.locale)

        font.pointSize: Style.textPointSize-2
        color: '#7e8d9e'
        selectionColor: '#7e8d9e'
        selectedTextColor: "white"
        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter

        readOnly: !control.editable
        validator: control.validator
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
    }

    up.indicator: Rectangle {
        x: control.mirrored ? 0 : parent.width - width
        height: parent.height
        implicitWidth: 20
        implicitHeight: 30
        color: control.up.pressed ? '#dee2e6' : '#bec6ce'
        border.color: enabled ? '#bec6ce' : '#dee2e6'

        Text {
            text: "+"
            font.pixelSize: control.font.pixelSize * 2
            color: '#428AC9'
            anchors.fill: parent
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }

    down.indicator: Rectangle {
        x: control.mirrored ? parent.width - width : 0
        height: parent.height
        implicitWidth: 20
        implicitHeight: 30
        color: control.down.pressed ? '#dee2e6' : '#bec6ce'
        border.color: enabled ? '#bec6ce' : '#dee2e6'

        Text {
            text: "-"
            font.pixelSize: control.font.pixelSize * 2
            color: '#428AC9'
            anchors.fill: parent
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 90
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code that actually runs. I'd also suggest searching in the bug tracker, because this warning is quite common.

Comment: Probably You used `Attribute` of `opengl` in your `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same problem and after some experiments seemed to find that it's somewhat connected to assigning literal values to the `value` property of `SpinBox`.

Something similar is also discussed [in this report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-97782), and these are other things asking for trouble when used in `SpinBox` mentioned there:

- references between internal elements of `SpinBox` (`contentItem`, `background`, `[up,down].indicator`'s)
- references to `parent` in internal elements
- assigning `id` to internal elements

After getting rid of all of that and also changing `value: 0` to `value: from` it automagically stopped warning me with the message in the original post.

Just as a reference, here's the snippet which works for me without the warning:

```
SpinBox
{
    id: control
    value: from

    from: 0
    to: 600

    editable: true
    enabled: true

    leftPadding: topPadding
    rightPadding: height

    contentItem: Item
    {
        anchors.left: control.left
        anchors.top: control.top
        anchors.bottom: control.bottom

        implicitWidth: input.implicitWidth
        implicitHeight: input.implicitHeight

        width: control.width - control.height
        height: control.height

        TextInput
        {
            id: input

            anchors.fill: parent

            text: control.textFromValue(control.value, control.locale)

            color: "black"
            horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter

            readOnly: !control.editable
            validator: control.validator
            inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
        }
    }

    up.indicator: Rectangle
    {
        anchors.top: control.top
        anchors.right: control.right
        anchors.topMargin: 1
        anchors.rightMargin: 1

        height: control.height / 2
        width: control.height

        color: "gold"
    }

    down.indicator: Rectangle
    {
        anchors.bottom: control.bottom
        anchors.right: control.right
        anchors.bottomMargin: 1
        anchors.rightMargin: 1

        height: control.height / 2
        width: control.height

        color: "orange"
    }

    background: Rectangle
    {
        implicitWidth: 100
        border.color: "red"
        border.width: 1
        radius: 2
    }
}
```